# NSString from NSData with the character: ﬂ

Tags: string, encoding, nsstring, byte, nsdata

How can I return back to an NSString from the byte date of the NSString containing this character: ﬂ ?

```
NSString *inflatedString01  = @"ﬂ";

// original code that was the problem!
NSData *dataOfString = [NSData dataWithBytes:[inflatedString01 UTF8String] length:[inflatedString length]];
// code that fixes the problem
//NSData *dataOfString = [inflatedString01 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //thanks zneak

NSLog(@"%@",inflatedString01);
NSLog(@"%i",[inflatedString01 length]);
NSLog(@"%@",dataOfString);
NSLog(@"%i",[dataOfString length]);

NSString *stringFromData = [NSString stringWithCString:[dataOfString bytes] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

NSLog(@"%@",stringFromData);
```

The output of the above gives:

```
2012-01-02 08:47:48.963 TestApp[74363:fe03] ﬂ
2012-01-02 08:47:49.262 TestApp[74363:fe03] 1
2012-01-02 08:47:49.540 TestApp[74363:fe03] <ef>
2012-01-02 08:47:49.924 TestApp[74363:fe03] 1
2012-01-02 08:47:50.787 TestApp[74363:fe03] (null)
```

I'd like to see ﬂ instead of (null) for the last NSLog output. I'm guessing there is a significance with the 'ef' output of NSData.

Comment: Actually, I think I got it, I tried:     NSData *dataOfString = [NSData dataWithBytes:[inflatedString01 UTF8String] length:strlen([inflatedString01 UTF8String])]; which got the correct length of the string byte data (I think!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the discrepancy of the character size versus the binary size. When you call `[NSString length]`, what you get is the number of logical characters in the string, not the number of bytes required to store it in an arbitrary encoding. The character ﬂ is one logical character for the `NSString` class, but its UTF-8 encoding is `ef ac 82`: it takes up 3 bytes.

Your call to `[NSData dataWithBytes:length:]` receives a pointer to these 3 bytes, but then `[inflatedString01 length]` tells that it's only one character and you pass that as the number of bytes; this is why your data contains only `ef`.

`strlen`, not being encoding-aware, will just count the number of bytes in a C string until it finds a zero, so it will accurately return the number of bytes in an UTF-8 string (as you noted in your comment).

The best solution would probably to simply call `[inflatedString01 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` to get the bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation zneak, I'll accept in 5 minutes :-)

Comment: @Rew, no problem :) also consider using `-[NSString dataUsingEncoding:]` to get the bytes.

Comment: Of course, will update the question for others, it got in there due to my trying of anything and everything (always helps to know what you're doing :-) )

Comment: I guess you meant +[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]; anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Rew, both Mac OS and iOS have a [`-[NSString dataUsingEncoding:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method.